# Why is plt.imshow so much quicker than plt.pcolor ?

Tags: python, image-processing, matplotlib, heatmap, imshow

I am trying to figure out as much data visualization tools as I can from 2D matrices (bonus points to any other good methods for looking at 2D matrices).

I generate a lot of heatmaps, where I've been told `pcolor` is the way to go (I now use `seaborn`).

**Why is `plt.imshow` SO much quicker than `plt.pcolor` when they are doing really similar operations?**

```
def image_gradient(m,n):
    """
    Create image arrays
    """
    A_m = np.arange(m)[:, None]
    A_n = np.arange(n)[None, :]
    return(A_m.astype(np.float)+A_n.astype(np.float)) 

A_100x100 = image_gradient(m,n)

%timeit plt.pcolor(A_100x100)
%timeit plt.imshow(A_100x100)

1 loop, best of 3: 636 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.4 ms per loop
```

Comment: A possible duplicate question? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470288/matplotlib-pcolor-very-slow-alternatives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering partially to your question, plt.imshow is much quicker than plt.pcolor **because they are not doing similar operations**. In fact, they do very different things.

According to the documentation, matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor returns a matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection, which can be slow compared to pcolormesh, which returns a matplotlib.collections.QuadMesh object. imshow, in the other hand, returns a matplotlib.image.AxesImage object. I did a test with pcolor, imshow and pcolormesh:

```
def image_gradient(m,n):
    """
    Create image arrays
    """
    A_m = np.arange(m)[:, None]
    A_n = np.arange(n)[None, :]
    return(A_m.astype(np.float)+A_n.astype(np.float)) 

m = 100
n = 100

A_100x100 = image_gradient(m,n)

%time plt.imshow(A_100x100)
%time plt.pcolor(A_100x100)
%time plt.pcolormesh(A_100x100)
```

and the results I get are:

```
imshow()
CPU times: user 76 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 76 ms
Wall time: 74.4 ms
pcolor()
CPU times: user 588 ms, sys: 16 ms, total: 604 ms
Wall time: 601 ms
pcolormesh()
CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 4 ms, total: 4 ms
Wall time: 2.32 ms
```

Clearly, for this particular example, pcolormesh is the most efficient one.