# Heat maps of large data with pyplot slow

Tags: python, performance, matplotlib, heatmap

I am working with a big set of data (240, 131000) and bigger. I am currently using the code below to plot this.

```
fig,ax = pyplot.subplots()
spectrum = ax.pcolor(waterfallplot, cmap='viridis')
pyplot.colorbar()
pyplot.show()
```

However, it's taking a very long time (30 min+) and the plot still hasn't shown up yet. A quick breakpoint check says the code gets to the `spectrum=` line, but doesn't go past. Looking at the memory on my computer, it hasn't even gotten close to the limit.

Does anyone have a better way of doing this?

Comment: You should add the tag related to the library you're using to plot...

Comment: @nbro Thank you! I added it.

Comment: Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470288/matplotlib-pcolor-very-slow-alternatives) and [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/pcolor_demo.html)?

Comment: @sascha I started at the second one in my research and that was after I exhausted `imshow` possibilities. I will look into `pcolormesh`, but do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: No, but i'm pretty sure, one of these 4 approaches will help you.

Comment: @sascha `pcolorfast` did what I was wanting. I must have overlooked it the first 8 times I read that one. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

`pcolorfast` works best for large arrays and updates quickly.